# Не работает пример парсера из книги

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Взял пример из книжки, но он не работает.

***Код:***

```py
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
        for tag in sp.find_all("a"):
            url = tag.get("href")
            if url is None:
                continue
                if "html" in url:
                    print("\n" + url)

news = "https://news.google.ru/"
Scraper(news).scrape()
```

Answer (score 2):

Не парсер не работает, а на странице нет ни одной ссылки с вхождением "html":

[image: скриншот]

Comment: это  как? что тогда написать, чтобы понять как парсер веб-контента работает?

Comment: Удали `if "html" in url:`

Comment: проблема в ссылке. там просто нет href . поменял ссылку на ссылку другого сайта... все гуд